# Develop/open dialog box like Data Validation in Excel add-in using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel add-in in React js. I want to open and handle dialog box (Like in Data Validation, show in image below too). I have seen "displayDialogAsync" a lot that takes html page but it seems different to me, Is it possible to achieve this thing?

I don't want to achieve this by Taskpane/Fluent UI, I want actual Excel dialog as show in image. Using react, I want to open this dialog from Ribbon buttons.

[image]